# Dems want to give to the states and the needy

Tags: word-usage

Does the word "Dems" sound neutral here? Is it negative sometimes?

> kenny strong tweeted in Replying to @JoeBiden
> **Dems want to give to the states and the needy**, but the republicans only want to protect their business from lawsuits. Republican corporation and business owners are not hurting. It’s a very sad situation.

Comment: **Dems** (shorthand for democrats) is neither negative nor positive, but it can be used in either favourable or unfavourable contexts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the general tone of the tweet, (which appears to view the Democrats in a more favourable light than the Republicans), I think that the term is being used affectionately.